# Generating a tall-and-thin random orthonormal matrix in SciPy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, orthogonal

I need to generate a tall-and-thin random column-orthonormal matrix in SciPy; that is, the number of rows `n` is far greater than the number of columns of `p` by many orders of magnitude (say `n = 1e5` and `p = 100`. I know that `scipy.stats.ortho_group` generates a square orthogonal matrix. However, in my case it's simply infeasible to generate an `n`-by-`n` random orthogonal matrix and then keep the first `p` columns... Is there a more time- and space- efficient approach?

Comment: I am sorry please refresh my memory. Aren't orthogonal matrices supposed to be square?

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan Yes, but a rectangular matrix can be row- or column- orthonormal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first generate a tall and thin random matrix, and then perform a qr decomposition.

```
a = np.random.random(size=(100000, 100))
q, _ = np.linalg.qr(a)
```

Here `q` is the matrix you want.

Comment: Ah, good idea. Although does it matter that `a` should be random uniform or random normal in order for `q` to be a truly random orthonormal matrix?

Comment: I think normal distribution might be better, but I'm not specialized in this domain. You might find this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0609050.pdf helpful, especially section 4, where this kind of issues are discussed in detail.

Comment: Note that this won't work for a short and wide random matrix, e.g. 
`>>> a = np.random.normal(0,1,(20,100)); >>> q, _ = np.linalg.qr(a); >>> q.shape; (20, 20)`

Comment: @ScottGigante How can a short and wide matrix be "column-orthonormal"? The number of columns is larger than the space dimension.

Answer (score 3):

To me `scipy.linalg.orth` was a little bit faster than `numpy.linalg.qr`:

```
a = np.random.random(size=(100000, 100))
q = scipy.linalg.orth(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a benchmarked answer. Note that I do some transposing so that this will work no matter whether that matrix is tall and thin (gives column-orthonormal) or short and wide (gives row-orthonormal).

```
def qr_method(n, m):
    X = np.random.normal(0,1,(n,m))
    if n < m:
        X = X.T
    Q, _ = np.linalg.qr(X)
    if n < m:
        Q = Q.T
    return Q

def orth_method(n, m):
    X = np.random.normal(0,1,(n,m))
    if n < m:
        X = X.T
    Q = scipy.linalg.orth(X)
    if n < m:
        Q = Q.T
    return Q

def ortho_group_method(n, m):
    Q = scipy.stats.ortho_group.rvs(max(n, m))[:min(n, m),:]
    if m < n:
        Q = Q.T
    return Q
```

The `ortho_group` method (aka make a square matrix and then take a subset) was so slow that I didn't benchmark it along with the others:

```
%timeit ortho_group_method(500, 20)
2.73 s ± 57.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Of the other two, the difference is negligible, by QR is slightly faster.

```
%timeit qr_method(10000, 200)
168 ms ± 3.78 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit orth_method(10000, 200)
193 ms ± 4.09 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Does it make a difference how tall the matrix is? For a very tall matrix, they are close to equivalent.

```
%timeit qr_method(100000, 20)
122 ms ± 1.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit orth_method(100000, 20)
130 ms ± 6.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

For a square matrix, QR is much faster.

```
%timeit qr_method(500, 500)
47.5 ms ± 202 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit orth_method(500, 500)
137 ms ± 1.32 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```